# Remove extra if in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable

How can I remove the **if (savedInstanceState != null)** in code below and do all with ? and !!

```
override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            search_bar.visibility =
                    if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("showSearchBar", false)) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: you have to declare search_bar as `var search_bar:Object?=null` and then you have to excess visibility by `search_bar!!.visibility`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use safe access `?.` on `savedInstanceState` and [compare nullable Boolean to `true`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#consuming-a-nullable-boolean):

```
val showSearchBar = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("showSearchBar", false) == true
search_bar.visibility = if (showSearchBar) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

Note this will hide the search bar even when `savedInstanceState` is null, so it's a slightly different behavior than originally, although it seems like desired behavior given that you passed `false` as default to `getBoolean` anyway.

By the way, [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) has a `View.isVisible` extension property that lets you write this as:

```
search_bar.isVisible =
    savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("showSearchBar", false) == true
```

Comment: It requires boolean, while this returns boolean?. adding !! will cause crash when savedInstanceState is null.

Comment: Nope, this won't crash. It's an idiom to check nullable Boolean https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#consuming-a-nullable-boolean

Comment: or  we can use elvis operator 
 search_bar.isVisible= savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("a", false) ?: false

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz you could, although `== true` is preferred compared to `?: false`, at least by JetBrains (See [style guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#using-nullable-boolean-values-in-conditions) and [github issue](https://github.com/yole/kotlin-style-guide/issues/18))